# How to change opacity of a parent form in c#

Tags: c#

I have a form with a button. I would like to change the opacity of this form when I click on the button which opens up a new form to 0.1. After I close the 2nd form and come back to the 1st form I would like to change the opacity back to 1.0.

So far I have this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public static class Snippet
{
    public static func()
    {
        // Get the active form
        System.Windows.Forms.Form activeForm = System.Windows.Forms.Form.ActiveForm;
                
        // Set the transparency level (e.g., 50% opacity)
        activeForm.Opacity = 0.5;
    
    }

}
```

But the problem is my whole application changes opacity and not just the active form with the button on it.

I have searched the forums regarding this topic, even tried ChatGPT, but was not able to find the correct answer regarding changing opacity of a specific windows form.

Comment: Why don't you set simply call `myLovelyForm.Opacity = 0.5;` when showing creating that form? ActiveForm is presumably the wrong form because you want to set Opacity before showing a form and then its not (yet) the ActiveForm.

Comment: 1stForm is acitve ... It has a button on it. After this button is pressed, the 1stForm opacity should change and than the 2ndForm should show up without any opacity. 
But for me the whole application gets opacity set ... You can see the desktop ...

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you click on a button, the window that contains it should become the active one and the function that you show should work. I think there is a lack of information to know why it is having that behavior.

But you can pass the form containing the button to the function:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public static class Snippet
{
    public static void func(Form form)
    {
       form.Opacity = 0.5;
    }
}
```

and call from button event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Snipped.func(this);
}
```

or without static class:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.Opacity = 0.5;
}
```

Comment: 1stForm with a button
https://i.ibb.co/xzySCCh/first.jpg

2ndForm after button is clicked
https://i.ibb.co/wYT75FD/second.jpg

as you see it makes the whole app transparent ... you can see the desktop ... even the toolbar and navigation ...

Comment: For some reason the ```System.Windows.Forms.Form activeForm = System.Windows.Forms.Form.ActiveForm;``` is giving me the whole application form and not the form of an opened window inside of my application.

Comment: I didn't know there is a difference for MDI applications. I have a MDI application ... So i need to use the ActiveMdiChild ...

Comment: MDIChild forms are not able to be transparent? :(

Comment: I managed to hide the ActiveMdiChild form with hide() and than show it back with show() ... I got what i wanted. To sum up in MDI applications you need to use ```System.Windows.Forms.Form.ActiveForm.ActiveMdiChild``` and than use this to hide() and show() the form.